# how to use QGroupBox in place of QButtonGroup

Tags: qt, button, qt4.7, qgroupbox, qbuttongroup

I'm trying to figure out how to use the QGroupBox widget in place of the QButtonGroup widget as the qt docs (link below) 'strongly advise against using it'.

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/q3buttongroup.html

The QButtonGroup had a handy method called `QtGui.QButtonGroup.checkedButton()` and I'm looking for a way to find the checked radio button contained in the QGroupBox. What is the new best practice for this?

Answer (score 8):

The QButtonGroup Still exists and is in use only its implementation has changed and is no longer a Widget. In qt designer the QButtonGroup is no longer in the widget menu, you now select the buttons you wish to associate with a group and right click to add a QButtonGroup.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This saved me quite a bit of time.